Is there a log for processes that request too much GPU memory on Linux for NVidia GPUs?
I would like to find a history for Nvidia GPUs where I can see when a process given by PID has requested GPU memory and it failed because of lack of available GPU memory. System would be Rocky 9 and the GPU NVIDIA A100 using MIGS.
Additional background - for budget reasons, way more than one model is loaded per GPU, so they can process immediately each new request. Also this allocation is dynamic.
Each model can and does have different memory requirements. A model can fail because of internal issues or because of miscalculation of available memory or (potentially) memory usage of a given model.
So using the memory snapshot given by doing the equivalent of "nvidia-smi" is not an adequate solution, as it does not tell how much memory is actually available for the very reason that one or more models might actually get loaded into memory.
So unfortunately, I do need a log for failed GPU memory requests similar to OOM killings to quickly see whether there is an issue with the memory calculation.

Did you try find what is happening using nvidia-smi and cuda-memcheck. These are very comprehensive and you might need to check the help to see which arguments fit best in your case.


No historical data is accumulated and stored by default, it's solely on you.
Failure to allocate VRAM must be handled by your application(s), the NVIDIA driver neither logs, nor reports such issues.
As for retrieving this information, you could use nvidia-smi, or nvidia-smi -l 1 (dump info every second), nvtop or nvidia-smi -q - dump all the info.


Thanks, but that would not be able to catch any request for more GPU memory than there is still left, would it?

These utilities don't track/log VRAM allocation errors either.
